# Reading default output of Fortran in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fortran

I have an output from old code in Fortran 77. The output is written with

```
write(NUM,*)
```

line. So basically, default format. Following is part of output:

```
1.25107598E-67  1.89781536E-61  1.28064971E-94  5.85754394-118  8.02718071E-94
```

I had a post-processing tool written in F77 and `READ(NUM,*)` read the input file correctly as:

```
1.25107598000000E-67  1.89781536000000E-61  1.28064971000000E-94  5.85754394000000E-118  8.02718071000000E-94
```

The problematic number is `5.85754394-118`. 
It will read correctly as it means `5.85754394E-118` in F77.

However, now I wrote a post-processing in python and I have a following line of code:

```
Z = numpy.fromstring(lines[nl], dtype=float, sep=' ')
```

which will read an output line by line (through loop on `nl`).
But when it reaches the `5.85754394-118` number it will stop reading, going to the next line of output and basically reading wrong number. Is there any way to read it in a correct way (default way of Fortran)?
I will guess I need to change `dtype` option but not have any clue.

Comment: you mean you fail to post-process your strangely formatted number?

Comment: Yes! that's right

Comment: Are you able to slightly modify the Fortran code which writes the corrupt value?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004824/for-three-digit-exponents-fortran-drops-the-e-in-the-output

Comment: I can write a small post-processing file in F77 which read the previous output and write it in a float format which python likes. But I wanted something in python itself. If there is no way, then I will change a format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post-process your output efficiently with a regular expression:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)\-(?=\d)")

output_line = "1.25107598E-67  1.89781536E-61  1.28064971E-94  5.85754394-118  8.02718071E-94 "
print(r.sub("E-",output_line))
```

result:

```
1.25107598E-67  1.89781536E-61  1.28064971E-94  5.85754394E-118  8.02718071E-94
```

`(?<=\d)\-(?=\d)` performs a lookbehind and lookahead for digits, and search for single minus sign between them. It replaces the minus sign by `E-`.