# IFORT/IFX differences in (ENx.y) output?

Tags: intel-fortran

I'm moving some code from the Intel IFORT x86 compiler to the IFX x64 compiler and noticed that the (EN..) format behaves differently.

For example a value of 1234567 output using (EN0.6) produces:

IFORT: 1.234567E+06

IFX: 1.234567+06

Note the missing 'E' in the IFX output.  Is this the correct behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: This question can certainly be asked here, but it seems it would even better suited the Intel site. With the `0` you are giving the compiler some freedom. I do not think that any of them are wrong.

Comment: The trouble with the missing 'E' is that other non-Fortran programs have problems reading it correctly...

Comment: This might be useful to anyone else with this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004824/for-three-digit-exponents-fortran-drops-the-e-in-the-output